# flask-mongoengine and document not accepting unique or primary_key arguments

Tags: python, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm trying out flask-mongoengine and mongohq and I'm having some difficulty getting it to declare my documents correctly.

I've declaed a db document like so:

```
class numbers(nodb.Document):
    numbers = nodb.StringField(required=True)
    simple_date = nodb.DateTimeField(required=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    date = nodb.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, required=True)
```

now when I add an entry to the document it's not taking my _id or even acknowledging that I've put in the unique or primary_key requirement.

```
test = numbers(
        _id=datetime.strptime(currentdate, "%m/%d/%Y").date(),
        simple_date=datetime.strptime(currentdate, "%m/%d/%Y").date(),
        numbers='12345'
    )
test.save()
```

now if I do those lines again, it creates another identical entry in the db and the requirements on simple_date appear to be ignored.  Not sure if I'm hitting a bug here or just doing something wrong?

Comment: Look like you do not have unique index. Can you show what print `db.numbers.getIndexes();` in mongo console for your database?

Comment: I get an empty list back for getIndexes().  Is mongoengine not creating the indexes for me from the definition?

Answer (score 1):

`Mongoengine` must create indexes if collection not exists yet. `Mongoengine` do not take care about data migration. So if you at first created collection without index and next describe index in model then index not created automatically. For your case you must create indexes manually or try drop your `numbers` collection **only for development database when data not necessary**.

Comment: I thought of that, and I've went through several iterations of trying only unique, or only primary_key, and each time I've dropped the collection so that it would build it again, but it still does not create new a new index for me.  I've found one other reference that included a meta tag for declaring the indexes but that doesn't seem to work either.  I'm wondering if this mongohq db that I'm using isn't potentially allowing me to do the creation?